# I need to remove dupilciate element that matches exactly

Tags: xslt

I have an input xml as follows. My target is to remove duplicate elements that matches exactly from one to another.

Input xml

```
<namespaces>
<namespace prefix="dc">http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/</namespace>
<namespace prefix="gz">http://www.tso.co.uk/assets/namespace/gazette</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xsl">http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform</namespace>
<namespace prefix="atom">http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xd">http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl</namespace> 
<namespace prefix="xs">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xhtml">http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml</namespace>
<namespace prefix="atom">http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xd">http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xs">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xhtml">http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml</namespace>
<namespace prefix="atom">http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xs">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
<namespace prefix="gz">http://www.tso.co.uk/assets/namespace/gazette</namespace>
<namespace prefix="gz">http://www.tso.co.uk/assets/namespace/gazette</namespace>
</namespaces>
```

and the expected output[from the above input xml snippet] should be as follows:

```
<namespaces>
<namespace prefix="dc">http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/</namespace>
<namespace prefix="gz">http://www.tso.co.uk/assets/namespace/gazette</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xsl">http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform</namespace>
<namespace prefix="atom">http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xd">http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl</namespace> 
<namespace prefix="xs">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
<namespace prefix="xhtml">http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml</namespace>
<namespace prefix="gz">http://www.tso.co.uk/assets/namespace/gazette</namespace>
</namespaces>
```

I need an xslt code to achieve this.
Any idea? please

Comment: You've asked 12 questions so far but accepted no answers - you might get a better response if you were to go back and [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) any answers you're happy with.  Accepting answers is the SO way to reward people for helping you out, and currently it looks like you're never satisfied with the help anyone gives you, which isn't a good way to encourage people to help you in future.

Comment: Hi, `Please accept my apologies for this` and thanks for this link. Actually, i am not aware of this how to accept the answer. Whenever, I got the right answer i thought myself that answer will be evaluated by someone, so that, I was waiting for that. Now only, i came to understand by your link. `I am SO sorry for my stupidity`. Henceforth, i am sure this won't be happen again. Now, I accepted  the right answers that helped me. Thanks a lot for your info and your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be interpreted as a grouping problem - you want to group the elements based on the combination of their `prefix` attribute and their string value, and then retain just the first element in each group.  In XSLT 2.0 this is a simple `for-each-group`

```
<xsl:template match="namespaces">
  <namespaces>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="namespace" group-by="concat(@prefix, ':', .)">
      <xsl:sequence select="." />
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </namespaces>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 1.0 you can define a key and use the Muenchian technique

```
<xsl:key name="nsKey" match="namespace" use="concat(@prefix, ':', .)" />

<xsl:template match="namespaces">
  <namespaces>
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace[
       generate-id() = generate-id(key('nsKey', concat(@prefix, ':', .))[1])]" />
  </namespaces>
</xsl:template>
```

(this assumes you only have one `namespaces` element in your document, if you have more than one then the technique still works but you need a more complex key including `generate-id(..)` to produce groups *per-parent* rather than *per-document*).